# Jquery .Ajax() Return Error 0

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web-services, iis

I wrote javascript in index.html with a login form. When I submit, I call a web service remotely to a server running IIS7. I get back a response when I run it with "Live Code" in Dreamweaver but when I run the index.html in a regular browser with the same code I get error type "0". The same thing happen when I copy those file and host it on the server and changing the web service path to localhost and opening it with a broswer.

I am suspecting that it has to do with access permission of something similar.
Here is the code, if more information is needed please let me know

```
$("#ButtonLogin").click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serverPath + "/test.asmx/LogIN",
        data: "{'UserName': '" + $('#TextBoxUsername').val() 
          + "', 'pwd': '" + $('#TextBoxPassword').val() + "'}", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (msg) { 
            AjaxLogInSucceeded(msg);} ,
        error: AjaxLogInFailed
    });
});
```

Comment: Is serverPath on the same domain as index.html?  Ajax calls are restricted by the same origin policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript.

Comment: I know this is old, but should be `{'UserName': $('#TextBoxUsername').val(), 'pwd': $('#TextBoxPassword').val()}` and not a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging ajax issues can seem complicated, but if you remember that you're just sending off a URL debugging becomes easier.  When dealing with these sorts of problems I use the Firefox "Live HTTP Headers" extension to see the URL with the CGI paramters that are being sent to the server.  I'd imagine that this could be quite helpful when running code generated by a system like Dreamweaver.

You can then just plug your ajax URL into your browser (or wget) and see what comes back.  Or if I'm writing the backend code also (usually the case) I can print out debugging status messages to help to identify the problem.

good luck!