# Pass a variable from one page to another PHP, jQuery, AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I am submitting a form with jQuery AJAX.

Each time I press submit I am getting the same error (in the console its RED).

When I am trying

```
  error: function(response) {
    console.log(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
}
```

the console.log says: error 0.

Here comes the funny part; If I keep spamming the submit-button, the Ajax says OK after 2nd try and after. It only fails the first time, but works the second. But thats kind of lame, I want it to work on the first try :)
Does anyone have any clue on errorreporting/any tips to make this work. 
ps. My var's are in Norwegian, but if you like I can post it.

EDIT:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(){
        // Lots of vars, I have checked them --> all good
        var fornavn = $('#fornavn').val();
        var etternavn = $('#etternavn').val();
        var adresse = $('#adresse').val();
        var overskrift = $('#overskrift').val();
        var beskrivelse = $('#beskrivelse').val();
        var epost = $('#epost').val();
        var tlf = $('#tlf').val();
        var postnr = $('#postnr').val();
        var poststed = $('#poststed').val();
        var hovedkategori = $('#hovedkategori').val();
        var underkategori = $('#underkategori').val();
        $.ajax({
         // tried with absolute link, same problem
            url: "../customcode/services/NyAnnonse1Validering.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{
            fornavn: fornavn,
            etternavn: etternavn,
            adresse: adresse,
            overskrift: overskrift,
            beskrivelse: beskrivelse,
            epost: epost,
            tlf: tlf,
            postnr: postnr,
            poststed: poststed,
            hovedkategori: hovedkategori,
            underkategori: underkategori
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 1)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                else
                    {

                        $('#error')
                        .html(data)
                        .addClass('error')
                        .fadeIn('fast');
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                error: function(response) {
    console.log(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
}
            });
    }); 
});
```

THE PHP FILE

```
    <?php
// henter variablene fra ajax
$fornavn=$_POST['fornavn'];
$etternavn=$_POST['etternavn'];
$adresse=$_POST['adresse'];
$overskrift=$_POST['overskrift'];
$beskrivelse=$_POST['beskrivelse'];
$epost=$_POST['epost'];
$tlf=$_POST['tlf'];
$postnr = $_POST['postnr'];
$poststed = $_POST['poststed'];
$hovedkategori = $_POST['hovedkategori'];
$underkategori = $_POST['underkategori'];
if($hovedkategori == "-")
    {
        $error[] = "- Velge en hovedkategori <br>";
    }
if(!$underkategori)
    {
        $error[] = "- Velge en underkategori <br>";
    }
if(!$overskrift)
    {
        $error[] = "- Annonsen må ha en overskrift <br>";
    }
if(!$beskrivelse)
    {
        $error[] = "- Annonsen må ha en beskrivelse <br>";
    }
if(!$fornavn)
    {
        $error[] = "- Fylle ut fornavn <br>";
    }
if(!$etternavn)
    {
        $error[] = "- Fylle ut etternavn <br>";
    }
if(!$adresse)
    {
        $error[] = "- Fylle ut adresse <br>";
    }
if(!$epost)
    {
        $error[] = "- Fylle ut epostadressen din <br>";
    }
if(!$tlf)
    {
        $error[] = "- Fylle ut telefonnummeret ditt <br>";
    }
if(!$postnr)
    {
        $error[] = "- Fylle ut postnummeret <br>";
    }
if(!$poststed)
    {
        $error[] = "- Fylle ut poststedet <br>";
    }
if($error)
    {
        echo "Du må fikse følgende før du kan fortsette: <br>";
        foreach ($error as $feilmelding){
            echo $feilmelding;
        }
    }
else
    {
        echo "1";
    }

?>
```

Comment: yes, please paste all relevant code.

Comment: error 0 is usually permission denied, if I'm not mistaken. While it's not an *answer* per se, this may help you find a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6968971/345585

Comment: are you missing the `return false;` at the end of the form submit handler ? If so maybe that's what's causing the problem, you hit submit, the ajax call initiates but the browser is going elsewhere and the ajax gets canceled and fails with an error 0.

Comment: @UnLoCo Hi! Thanks for the reply :) It worked with the return false at the bottom of the code(but I had to remove the password in my ftp-server first) But this was just an Ajax trial.. and I figured out AJAX was not the best for validation. So I quit the whole AJAX idea